# jQuery draggable(), on drag perform a dynamic function

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a jQuery draggable() function and on drag is executing several other functions based on an if. Something like this:

```
$("div.element").draggable({
    drag: function() {
            if  (a=1){
                function1();
                }
            if  (a=2){
                function2();
                }   
            if  (a=3){
                function3();
                }   
    }
});
```

There are many variables involved and I am looking to optimize this from the performance perspective point of view. Is it possible to make the draggable "know" what function to perform on drag without doing the `if` checking each time. Something like on drag do just function2() and function3().

Thank you

Comment: What determines which function should run?

Comment: An .attr request; if ($("someElement").attr("fontsize")){do this function}, not sure yet how to verify if an attr exists or not but this is the idea...

Comment: This does not really explain what function should run under which circumstances.

Comment: OK, maybe this should be better explained:
   if  ($("#layer0").hasClass("fontsize")){
    function1();
    }
   if  ($("#layer0").hasClass("color")){
    function2();
    } 
   if  ($("#layer0").hasClass("lineheight")){
    function3();
    }

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain it better. On drag of an element the function will check if other elements have some attributes or classes and according to this some functions will be executed

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery data to store the appropriate function object right with the draggable elements:

```
// declare the appropriate function for each element
$("select elements that need function1").data("dragFunction", function() {
  // whatever
});
$("select elements that need function2").data("dragFunction", function() {
  // whatever
});

// and then... just execute whatever function is stored in "dragFunction"
$("div.element").draggable({
  drag: function() { return $(this).data("dragFunction")(); }
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure if it will work in my case but I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: @Mircea: Maybe it is not exactly what you need, but on the other hand: I think you are doing premature optimization here. The use case (manually dragging an element with the mouse) is not exactly heavy load. A few unused `if` statements won't slow it down.